# SQL question about counting

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, count, aggregate

I want to make a query so that I can grab only Locations that have at least 50 Places.

I have a table of Locations:

```
Id, City, Country
1, Austin, USA
2, Paris, France
```

And a table of Places connected to Locations by Location_id

```
Id, Name, Details, Location_id
1, The Zoo, blah, 2
2, Big Park, blah, 2
```

I can join them like so:

SELECT places.name, places.id, locations.country, locations.city
FROM places
INNER JOIN locations
ON places.location_id = locations.id

by how can I only get the results of cities that have at least 50 places and order them by the largest amount?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK I've seen that the above answers are almost there but have some mistakes, so just posting the correct version:

```
SELECT locations.country, locations.city, COUNT(*) as count_of_places
FROM places
     INNER JOIN locations ON places.location_id = locations.id
GROUP BY locations.country, locations.city
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 50
ORDER BY count_of_places;
```

Comment: +1 if not for being the only one to actually have a working query <g>.

Comment: The order by starts with the lowest amount, actually. Should it be DESC?

Answer (score 4):

Use a [GROUP BY with a HAVING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) clause.

```
SELECT locations.country, locations.city, COUNT(*)
FROM places
     INNER JOIN locations ON places.location_id = locations.id
GROUP BY locations.country, locations.city
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 50
```

Comment: Just missing
... COUNT(*) as count_of_places
...
ORDER BY count_of_places DESC

Comment: The problem is that after grouping by places you're not going to have the proper `count(*)` grouped by location.

Comment: Not sure if this works: you're grouping by places.id, but (assuming the Id column in places is a Unique Key) this means all groups have one member.

Comment: I have no idea why people are upvoting you. Your query will return 0 rows, since you're `count(*)` will always return 1.

Comment: Whoops, haven't noticed that this is wrong, it should be grouping ONLY by Locations and not by Places!

Comment: @Eric, you're right offcourse, my bad. The crux was the GROUP BY with the HAVING clause though. I switched to *automatic mode/shutdown brain activity* writing the query itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `having` clause to limit these rows by the value of an aggregate column. Also, MySQL allows you to use lazy `group by`s, so you can absolutely take advantage of this:

```
select
    l.country,
    l.city,
    p.name,
    p.details,
    count(*) as number_of_places
from
    locations l
    inner join places p on
        l.id = p.location_id
group by
    l.id
having
    count(*) >= 50
order by
    number_of_places,
    l.country,
    l.city,
    p.name
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile - whatever is outside of aggregate functions in SELECT needs to be in GROUP BY.

Comment: @andrew: Not in MySQL. In SQL Server, it does. That's what I meant by the "lazy `group by`s" of MySQL. Brilliant, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat unperformant, but should work:

> `SELECT places.name, places.id, sq.country, sq.city, sq.counter`
>   `FROM (SELECT Locations.id, country,city, count(*) as counter FROM Locations`
>   `JOIN Places ON (Locations.Id=Places.Location_id)`
>   GROUP BY locations.id HAVING count(*) >= 50) AS sq
>   JOIN Places ON (sq.id=Places.Location_id)
>   ORDER BY counter DESC`

P.S. The exact syntax may vary depending on the database, I'm not sure if this is `mysql`-compatible as is.